# MPMoviePlayerViewController shifts UIView behind Status Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, statusbar

After playing a movie more than once on iOS 7 using a MPMoviePlayerViewController, the entire screen shifts behind the status bar. I've accounted for the changes iOS 7 made to use the full screen when the app launches by adding the following code in the app delegate

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
{
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    [application setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];

    self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
    self.window.frame =CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
}
```

which brings up the initial screen perfectly. However, on that screen is a button which plays a video and exits with the following methods

```
- (void)playFullScreenMovie
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:vidURL];
    self.playerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    // Register this class as an observer
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
    object:self.playerVC.moviePlayer];

    [[self playerVC].moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self presentViewController:self.playerVC animated:NO completion:nil];
}

// When the movie is done, release the controller.
-(void)movieFinishedCallback: (NSNotification*) aNotification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie = [aNotification object];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    removeObserver: self
    name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
    object: theMovie];

   [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
}
```

When the presenting screen returns, it's shifted up, behind the status bar.

Solutions that haven't worked include:

1. Adding the same logic in the app delegate after the [self
   dismissMovie...]. But the self.view.window is nil because the
   presenting view isn't onscreen yet. Even reseting it in
   viewWillAppear, when self.view.window is not nil, doesn't work.
2. Attempts to update [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
   window] after [self dismissMovie...] doesn't fully work either. The
   window and status bar appear correctly, but the view doesn't.
   Attempts to change the frame in viewDidAppear were unsuccessful.
3. This article from apple didn't help because after adding all missing
   constraints, all of the images on the screen were skewed, thus
   diverting attention from the original problem.
   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html.
4. Efforts to correct screen shifts prior to the release of that
   article in January of 2014 haven't work on iOS 7.
5. Using a push segue to another view controller then unwinding back to the presenting 
   view doesn't work either. It's still shifted up.

Your comments, suggestions, advice and/or an explanation are greatly appreciated.